# Slow startup (asp.net website, entityframework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I know this kind of question has been asked manytimes, but those topics I found didn't help me much.

I've a asp.net website, very simple one, with a very simple default page, which require some data (just some) from the database. I'm using the Enity Ado.net framework for the database. I also set the Model's "Lazy Loading Enabled" to False. I just don't know why it took so long to start the first time I access the website. After that, the speed is ok.

I'll be very appreciated if someone can help me to find what'm I doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It probably need time to set up the database as well as the express IIS web server

Answer (score -2):

If you go and search for it on Microsofts´ Website you will find enough resources that will answer your question. I believe to answer questions here at SO while there exist somewhere else, is just wrong.

### Compiling on First Request

> By default, ASP.NET Web pages and code
>   files are compiled dynamically when users first request a resource,
>   such as an ASP.NET page (.aspx file), from a Web site. After pages and
>   code files have been compiled the first time, the compiled resources
>   are cached, so that subsequent requests to the same page are extremely
>   efficient. ASP.NET supports the dynamic compilation of ASP.NET pages
>   (.aspx files), ASP.NET Web services (.asmx files), ASP.NET HTTP
>   handlers (.ashx files) and ASP.NET application files (Global.asax), as
>   well as other files, such as source code and class files. For more
>   information about ASP.NET file types, see Web Site File Types. For
>   more information about the ASP.NET compilation process, see the
>   "Compilation Life Cycle" section of ASP.NET Application Life Cycle
>   Overview.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Luke, by mentioning compiling, do you mean publishing the website ?

I uploaded the published website to the host, so i think  this won't help my situation, do you have any other ideas ? thanks very much !